# Adding more fields to registration form

Tags: laravel-backpack

for my project I need to add a birthdate to the registration form.
I've tried to use the documentation at: [documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/base-how-to#add-one-or-more-fields-to-the-register-form-1)

But that one does not work, when I follow those steps I just get a white screen with register.php on it.
Has anyone else ever tried to do this and succeeded thanks!

Comment: are you using laravel/ui for auth ?

Comment: No I use Laravel Backpack for authentication

Comment: Please share some code so that we can help you identify the issue and propose a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps and see if this resolves your problem:

1. Create a `RegisterController` by overriding the default one. Remember to add validation for your field and populate the value when saving to the `User` model.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController as BackpackRegisterController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends BackpackRegisterController
{
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $user_model_fqn = config('backpack.base.user_model_fqn');
        $user = new $user_model_fqn();
        $users_table = $user->getTable();
        $email_validation = backpack_authentication_column() == 'email' ? 'email|' : '';

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            backpack_authentication_column() => 'required|' . $email_validation . 'max:255|unique:' . $users_table,
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'birth_date' => 'required|date:dd/mm/yyyy'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user_model_fqn = config('backpack.base.user_model_fqn');
        $user = new $user_model_fqn();

        return $user->create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            backpack_authentication_column() => $data[backpack_authentication_column()],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'birth_date' => $data['birth_date']
        ]);
    }
}
```

2. Override the `RegisterController` in `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // override register controller
        $this->app->bind(
            \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class,
            \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController::class
        );
    }
    
    //
}
```

3. Assuming you are using the Tabler theme, make a copy of the form in your application and add the extra field:

`resources/views/vendor/backpack/theme-tabler/auth/register/inc/form.blade.php`

```php
<h2 class="card-title text-center my-4">{{ trans('backpack::base.register') }}</h2>
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('backpack.auth.register') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="name">{{ trans('backpack::base.name') }}</label>
        <input autofocus tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
        @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ backpack_authentication_column() }}">{{ trans('backpack::base.'.strtolower(config('backpack.base.authentication_column_name'))) }}</label>
        <input tabindex="2" type="{{ backpack_authentication_column()==backpack_email_column()?'email':'text'}}" class="form-control {{ $errors->has(backpack_authentication_column()) ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="{{ backpack_authentication_column() }}" id="{{ backpack_authentication_column() }}" value="{{ old(backpack_authentication_column()) }}">
        @if ($errors->has(backpack_authentication_column()))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first(backpack_authentication_column()) }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="password">{{ trans('backpack::base.password') }}</label>
        <input tabindex="3" type="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" id="password" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="password_confirmation">{{ trans('backpack::base.confirm_password') }}</label>
        <input tabindex="4" type="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="form-label" for="birth_date">Birth Date</label>
        <input tabindex="3" type="date" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('birth_date') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="birth_date" id="birth_date" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('birth_date'))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('birth_date') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <button tabindex="5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                {{ trans('backpack::base.register') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

for that,
disable all of Backpack's auth routes and force to use Backpack the default guard in `config/backpack/base.php`

```
'setup_auth_routes' => false,
.............
'guard' => null,
```

then differentiate between different users in `app\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin` middleware

then use a custom auth or laravel/ui or breeze packages to customize views there